# Get ID from <td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have `<td id="checkb1" class="checkba">`

I want to get the value of the id when I click on

```
$('.checkba').click(function() {

    var my_var = $('.checkba').attr('id');
    alert(my_var);

});
```

The alert shows checkba not the id, checkb1.

Appreciate all assistance.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: @vivin you should also take into consideration, of people providing the correct answers

Comment: 134 asked questions with 44% accept-rate is a little on the low side in my book. But fair enough.

Comment: @vivin please check all 134 questions for answers that work out, and then comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `this`, to refer to the element you clicked on, like this:

```
$('.checkba').click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Otherwise [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets the attribute from the *first* matched element.